# How is CurvatureConfidenceRegion in FittedModel from NonlinearModelFit calculated?

Tags: fitting

I have a `FittedModel` from `NonlinearModelFit` for which the determination of the `FitCurvatureTable` can be extremely slow. These curvature diagnostics are part of the output in a large dynamic interface, and I would prefer to not have to tell the user to use <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to interrupt the calculation. On the plus side, it seems that I can use a (seemingly) undocumented feature of `FittedModel`, `EvaluationMonitor`, to interrupt the calculation using the technique I employed in answering [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/203966/interrupt-a-fit-minimization-without-interrupting-overall-evaluation) for interrupting a fit. However, if the user is willing to sit through the long calculation, I would like for them to be able to update the `CurvatureConfidenceRegion` portion of the table for a modified `ConfidenceLevel` without having to go back through the whole calculation.

I have implemented something similar for the `MeanPredictionBands` and `SinglePredictionBands` by storing the `MeanPredictionErrors` and `SinglePredictionErrors` and multiplying by:

```
Quantile[NormalDistribution[0, 1], (1 + confidenceLevel)/2]*{-1,1}
```

and then adding the fit values. However, I don't see how to do something similar for `CurvatureConfidenceRegion`, because I don't know how it is calculated relative to the `ConfidenceLevel`.

So, my question: if I have a `CurvatureConfidenceRegion` for a given value of `ConfidenceLevel`, is there a straightforward way to calculate that `CurvatureConfidenceRegion` for a different value of `ConfidenceLevel`?

Comment: I think you mean `ConfidenceLevel` as the `NonlinearModelFit` parameter.  If the fitted model is `nlm`, why not use `nlm["CurvatureConfidenceRegion"]` ? The values of the other two parameters in `FitCurvatureTable` don't change with the changing of the `ConfidenceLevel`.  (Your users sound pretty sophisticated if they need varying confidence levels for the `CurvatureConfidenceRegion` statistic.)

Comment: You are correct that I meant `ConfidenceLevel`. I will correct that in the OP. Yes, I can do just the calculation for `CurvatureConfidenceRegion`, which will save some time, but in my context even that calculation still can take minutes. So I am still interested in whether there is a scaling that can be used from one `ConfidenceLevel` to another. Re: the sophistication of my users, I am allowing them to change the `ConfidenceLevel` for the prediction bands and for the parameter estimate confidence range, and thought that I should be consistent and use the same `ConfidenceLevel` for everything.

Comment: I don't know what statistic is being calculated but it appears that it only depends on the number of samples, number of parameters, and the confidence level.  It is NOT dependent on the values of the data.  That doesn't help you but it does suggest that there is a function used that can be calculated independently of the data and model fit.  Maybe asking Wolfram, Inc. directly would supply the function used.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the `CurvatureConfidenceRegion` statistic is just a function of the number of observations, number of parameters, and the confidence level.  The actual data (both the predictor and response variables) and the model being fit seem to have nothing to do with it.  Therefore one can create a simple model and get the value for the `CurvatureConfidenceRegion` for any confidence level.

```
ccr[n_, np_, cl_] := NonlinearModelFit[Transpose[{Range[n]/n, Range[n]/n}],
   Sum[a[i] z^i, {i, np}], Table[a[i], {i, np}], z, 
   ConfidenceLevel -> cl]["CurvatureConfidenceRegion"]

ccr[20, 3, 95/100]
(* 0.559299 *)
```

Obviously, there is some underlying function that *Mathematica* uses but this seems to be a quick and dirty workaround until that exact function is known.  It would also be of interest for the documentation to state to what use that statistic is good for (and with a reference would be even better).

***Addition:***

As evidence that it doesn't matter about the data or the model here is a modification of the above function using random samples from a bivariate normal distribution with a slightly different model:

```
ccrRandom[n_, np_, cl_] := NonlinearModelFit[
   RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, {1, 2}, 0.8], n],
   Sum[a[i] z^(4 i), {i, np}], Table[a[i], {i, np}], z, 
   ConfidenceLevel -> cl]["CurvatureConfidenceRegion"]

Table[ccrRandom[20, 3, 95/100], {i, 10}]
(* {0.559299, 0.559299, 0.559299, 0.559299, 0.559299, 0.559299, 0.559299, 0.559299, 0.559299, 0.559299} *)

ccr[20, 3, 95/100]
(* 0.559299 *)
```